# ORA-01722 : invalid number throws when adding subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an error ORA-01722 in my query. 
This code gets me the list of commands. I need to add a subquery to get only the last ordered commands. The following code works well (generated with business object) and I tried to add the lines I left in commentary

```
SELECT
ltrim(SAP_MARA.MATNR,'0'),
SAP_MAKT.MAKTX,
SAP_MARA.MTART,
SAP_MARA.MATKL,
SAP_EKKO.EKGRP,
SAP_EKPA.LIFN2,
SAP_EKKO.EBELN,
SAP_EKPO.netwr,
SAP_EKKO.AEDAT
-- r.lastDate
FROM
SAP_MARA,
SAP_MAKT,
SAP_EKKO,
SAP_EKPA,
SAP_EKPO
--,( select EBELN , max(AEDAT) as lastDate from SAP_EKKO group by EBELN) r 
WHERE
( SAP_EKKO.MANDT=SAP_EKPO.MANDT and SAP_EKKO.EBELN=SAP_EKPO.EBELN  )
AND  ( SAP_MAKT.MATNR(+)=SAP_MARA.MATNR
  and SAP_MAKT.SPRAS(+)='F'  )
AND  ( SAP_MARA.MATNR(+)=SAP_EKPO.MATNR  )
AND  ( SAP_EKPO.EBELN like '45%'
and SAP_EKPO.MATNR<>' '  )
AND  ( SAP_EKKO.EBELN like '45%' and SAP_EKKO.LIFNR<>' '  )
AND  ( SAP_EKPA.MANDT=SAP_EKKO.MANDT and SAP_EKPA.EBELN=SAP_EKKO.EBELN  )
AND  ( SAP_EKKO.BUKRS= '1000'  )
 --and  SAP_EKKO.AEDAT = r.lastDate
;
```

The subquery works too when I'm calling it as a query.
I know this error comes from a try to convert a string into a number (probably in WHERE clause) but I don't figure why this occures only when I add this few lines.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Not an answer, but you should seriously consider moving away from the archaic join syntax you are using.  Instead, use modern join syntax.  This would, at the very least, make your query easier to understand, thereby increasing the chance that you get help on this site.

Comment: Are both columns ebeln.aedat and sap_ekko.aedat of type date? Can you reduce your query to a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I know this is an old structure but as I said, it's auto generated code, I'm looking for custom SQL code to write in BO instead of using their filter system. So if, Later, I missclic on BO, it will be easier to just add 3 rows in the code instead of finding a solution where all the joins are "modern" @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ all the date columns are in a date format. I will try to reduce it

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ I did post an answer.

Comment: @Verd'O in your question you join by the date, in your answer (I'd append this to your question instead of an answer) you join by a number. Is that correct? + your query cant work because of ambigious column names(Command_Number)

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ yes, my bad, in any case, it should be joined by date. Anyway thanks for your time, when you move the subquery in the clause where there is no error.. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you move the self join, you should be able to avoid the error. Try the following:

```
SELECT
ltrim(SAP_MARA.MATNR,'0'),
SAP_MAKT.MAKTX,
SAP_MARA.MTART,
SAP_MARA.MATKL,
k.EKGRP,
SAP_EKPA.LIFN2,
k.EBELN,
SAP_EKPO.netwr,
k.AEDAT
FROM
SAP_MARA,
SAP_MAKT,
SAP_EKKO k,
SAP_EKPA,
SAP_EKPO
WHERE
( SAP_EKKO.MANDT=SAP_EKPO.MANDT and SAP_EKKO.EBELN=SAP_EKPO.EBELN  )
AND  ( SAP_MAKT.MATNR(+)=SAP_MARA.MATNR
  and SAP_MAKT.SPRAS(+)='F'  )
AND  ( SAP_MARA.MATNR(+)=SAP_EKPO.MATNR  )
AND  ( SAP_EKPO.EBELN like '45%'
and SAP_EKPO.MATNR<>' '  )
AND  ( SAP_EKKO.EBELN like '45%' and SAP_EKKO.LIFNR<>' '  )
AND  ( SAP_EKPA.MANDT=SAP_EKKO.MANDT and SAP_EKPA.EBELN=SAP_EKKO.EBELN  )
AND  ( SAP_EKKO.BUKRS= '1000'  )
and  k.AEDAT = (select max(AEDAT) from SAP_EKKO k2 where k2.ebeln = k.ebeln)
;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works well. Do you have an idea why it didn't thow the error?

Comment: Because instead of pulling all EBELN and max(AEDAT) as a separate table, it's only pulling the EBELN  and max(AEDAT) for each row already being returned. If you want to find the offending EBELN, then I would do a select distinct EBELN on SAP_EKKO, and compare to what's being returned by this query. I imagine you'll find a null value or something else out of the ordinary that's not returned by your original query, but was included in your question query.

Answer (score 0):

I did simplify the code. The command number format is NUMBER.

Hope it helps.

```
Select 
Command_Number,
LastDateOrder
from 
SAP_EKKO,
( select Command_Number , max(DATE) as lastDate from SAP_EKKO group by 
Command_Number) r 
where
SAP_EKKO.Command_Number = r.Command_Number
```